# How to send multiple JMS messages Point to Point JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for performance testing.I am using JMS point to point sampler.
I have 30000 raw message which is needed to push in websphere mq?
Can anyone let me know how to accomplish this?

Note: A raw message can be used once.NO DUBLICATION ALLOWED.

Thanks in Advance,

AJ

Answer (score 0):

JMeter offers several functions which return random data, for instance:

1. [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generates random integer
2. [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates random string
3. [__UUID](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - generates GUID-like structure
4. [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - returns current thread number
5. [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) - can be used to get current iteration

See [official documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more information on above and other useful functions.